# Is this an efficient way of filling a data frame with API requests in r?

Tags: r

I am attempting to retrieve 1-minute open price on BTCUSDT through Binance's API. They have a limit of 1500 candles per request. The data is from 2019-09-09 to 2023-03-15. I'm self-taught and foresee myself using this method often in the future, so I would like to know if this the proper way of doing so. With 1231 requests, this process takes about 15 minutes. Also, I'm familiar with latex formatting but not code formatting on this website, so bear with me, and please correct any mistakes I make. TIA.

```
library(httr)
library(magrittr)
library(xts)

base_url <- "https://fapi.binance.com"
path1 <- "/fapi/v1/klines?symbol=BTCUSDT&interval=1m&startTime="
path2 <- "&limit=1500"
fxn <- get("GET")

## Total hours
total_hours = as.integer(as.Date("2023-03-15") - as.Date("2019-09-09")) * 24

## API requests needed
requests =  (total_hours * 60) / 1500

## Available data starts 2019-09-09
startTime = (as.numeric(as.POSIXct("2019-09-09 00:00:00 EST", origin = "1970-01-01")) * 1000)

## Create data frame of opening prices
prices = data.frame(matrix(ncol = 1))
colnames(prices) = "Open"

## Fill prices data frame
for(i in 1:requests){
  url <- paste0(base_url, path1, startTime, path2)
  call <- fxn(url)
  response <- content(call)
  prices %<>% add_row(Open = as.double(sapply(response, "[[", 2)))
  startTime = startTime + (1500*60000)
  
  print(i)
}
```

Comment: No, adding rows to a data frame is not efficient. You should create the data frame as big as you want it to be filled with `NA` values (*pre-allocation*) and then replace the `NA`s as you go.

Comment: That said, it's very possible that 99% of your execution time is waiting for the API results, in which case making the part of the code on your end more efficient will not make any noticeable difference. You should test to see where the slow parts are (profiling your code).

Comment: @GregorThomas Thank you. Could you direct me to any resources where I could learn about code profiling?

Comment: https://support.posit.co/hc/en-us/articles/218221837-Profiling-R-code-with-the-RStudio-IDE gives a thorough approach. For this simple case you could do it more simply - just assigning timestamps to variables and subtracting to record the execution time of getting the response and adding to the data frame.